# Is it "Yours faithfully" when ending an impersonal email to a company NAME?

Tags: salutations

Can someone address the grey area her: If you're addressing a company name via email, for the first time, and have no idea who the recipient is, you are using a "name" but there is nothing informal to suggest the salutation, "sincerely". At the same time you want to show a little know-how. Please clarify? My instincts go against the general guidance given previously, in this example.

Comment: As a request for writing advice (the niceties of correspondence), this belongs on another site, but I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you cannot use formal language in your correspondence?
If not you may address it to a company name, begin the letter with "Dear Sir/Madam", and end it with "Yours sincerely".

Comment: Formal language to a body corporate would be "Dear Sirs", not "Dear Sir/Madam".

Answer (score 0):

You may end such a letter with "Yours sincerely" or "Best regards".

Comment: "Best regards" is highly informal and would not convey the impression the OP wishes to give.